# how to start a standalone quartz job

Tags: maven, cron, quartz-scheduler

```
public class CronTriggerExample
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger =
                TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
                        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/2 * * * * ?")).build();

        // schedule it
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        return;
    }
    catch (SchedulerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

i am using quartz to set up some crons on my server. But how can i execute this file on server so that this can schedule the cron. i tried to use plugin 
"org.codehaus.mojo" to execute the java file. But it always create a new trigger when ever i run mvn install as deamon. What to do so that it will reinitialize the cron on "mvn install".

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written your main method, the application will exit just after scheduling the job. Although the quartz task is scheduled in a different thread, when the process ends it kills all active threads.

Simply add a `while (true) {}` statement after your `scheduler.scheduleJob` to keep the application running.

Now, just have maven build your jar and execute `java -jar myjar.jar`

Comment: After running "mvn clean install -DskipTests" it never returns to terminal.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. maven just builds your project. Especially with `-DskipTests=true` (do you have the "=true" part?), no code is executed. There might be something else with your POM.

Comment: If you mean that when you run your jar, it doesn't return to the terminal, well that is the result of the while(true). Your application won't exit until it is interrupted (i.e. Ctrl-C). If you want it run unattended, let me know you have a few options for that too, including just running your jar with plain old CRON (linux) or Windows task manager. More elegantly (but also more Rube-Golberg) would be to create a service.

Comment: thanks for quick response, 
Yes i want to run that unattended on server and when ever i will run "mvn install" on server it will terminate the previous trigger and setup new one.

Comment: Simplest would be not to use quartz - just use the operating system scheduler that executes your jar and exits (whatever is in HelloJob.java). If you really need a service, I've used apache procrun (I'm assuming your on Windows). Take a look: http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html If it runs as a service keep the while(true) loop so it doesn't exit. When you stop the service you'll be interrupting that loop.

Comment: mvn install is just going to give you a jar file in /target. It's the jar file you put on the server. You do not need maven runtime there. I have a feeling from your comments you may be confusing building your project (maven) vs. running your project (java -jar...).